# Linux on a Xilinx FPGA without EDK

Tags: fpga, xilinx, linux, vivado, xilinx-sdk

I appologise if this seems like a dumb question, but is it possible to get a Xilinx FPGA (specifically, the Artix-7 35T) to run Linux without the use of Xilinx's EDK? I have found some tutorials like [this one](http://billauer.co.il/blog/2011/08/linux-microblaze-howto-tutorial-primer-1/) but they seem to require the EDK (of which there is no free version I believe).

I am currently using Vivado and the Xilinx SDK and I can get a simple C "Hello World" program to run, but I am having problems with trying to get it to run Linux. Can I implement Linux using those two tools? Is there a good guide anywhere on how to do it?

Comment: Look at the Yocto system and the "meta-xilinx" layer.

Answer (score 1):

@Blair Fonville is right, you can only run Linux on a Sofprocessor in FPGA. Microblaze can run Linux, http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/MicroBlaze. But I think it will need a significant number of logic resources for that, I am not sure whether this Artix can do that.

Have a look on Zynq chip from Xilinx. There are relatively inexpensive SBCs with Zynq which has dual Cortex A9 inside which can run Linux just fine.

Comment: These two statements are contradicting themselves: "you can only run Linux on a Sofprocessor in FPGA" & "has dual Cortex A9 inside which can run Linux just fine"..

Comment: Nope, they are not.

Comment: AFAIK, Zynq is an FPGA with hard CPUs inside, right?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the chip details, but if the Artix supports microblaze soft cores then it will work fine. In Vivado, build the system as a block design (IP Integrator) and use SDK to build the kernel.